# Using vector to minimize heap allocations causes seg faults

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, allocation, stack-memory

Within a function, I have created a vector with generous amounts of space to which I push a runtime determined amount of objects(`Edge`). Other objects, however, maintain pointers to the `Edges` within the vector. Occasionally the entire program seg faults because a pointer becomes invalid, and I suspect that this happens when the vector reaches capacity and reallocates, thereby invalidating the memory addresses.

Is there any way around this? Or perhaps is there another solution to grouping together heap allocations?

**Note**: that the primary motivation for this is to minimize heap allocations, for this is what is slowing down my algorithm. Initially I had `vector<Edge *>` and every element added was individually allocated. Batch allocation increased the speed dramatically, but the `vector` method described here invalidates pointers.

Your code example, as requested:
This is the vector I declare as a stack var:

```
vector<Edge> edgeListTemp(1000);
```

I then add to it as such, using an rvalue overload:

```
edgeListTemp.push_back(Edge{edge->movie, first, second});
```

`Node` objects keep pointers to these:

```
first->edges.push_back(&edgeListTemp.back());
second->edges.push_back(&edgeListTemp.back());
```

Where `edges` is declared as follows:

```
std::vector<Edge *> edges; /**< Adjacency list */
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That's the nature of using a `std::vector`. **Don't do it that way**. Can't you use a `std::list` instead?

Comment: You shouldn't have pointers pointing to internal items in a vector to begin with.  Use a `std::list`, as the other comment suggests.

Comment: Why not use shared pointers to edges in the array instead? I assume by "maintain pointers to the Edge" means you use the address of an index into the vector?

Comment: The addresses of items stored in a `std::vector` aren't stable. You could have read that from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The appeal of a `vector` was that it allocates rarely. I would imagine that a `list` allocates much more frequently as it probably does so every insert

Comment: Also can the people that downvoted because of the minimal, complete, and verifiiable example retract their vote cause they just banned me from asking questions :|

Comment: `vector<Edge> edgeListTemp(1000);` declares a vector with 1000 default constructed Edge objects in it. `edgeListTemp.push_back(Edge{edge->movie, first, second});` adds number 1001, 1002, etc. Use reserve to reserve space for at least N elements, not what you're doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions:

- if you already know the maximum number of elements in advance, do a `reserve` over the vector from the start; elements won't be reallocated until you reach that size;
- if you don't know the maximum number of elements/don't want to preallocate the maximum size for performance reasons *but* you only add/remove elements from the end (or from the start) of the vector, use an `std::deque` instead. `std::deque` guarantees that pointers to elements aren't invalidated as long as you only push/pop from front/back;
- `std::list` guarantees to never invalidate references to elements, but it introduces several serious performance penalties (no O(1) addressing, one allocation for each node);
- if you want to ignore the problem completely, add a layer of indirection, and store into the vector *pointers* to elements allocated over the heap; even better, make a vector of `std::shared_ptr` and always use it to keep references to the elements; this obviously has the disadvantage of needing one allocation for each element, which may or may not be acceptable, depending on your use case.

Comment: I see. The primary problem I am trying to solve however, is not pointer invalidation but rather minimizing the number of allocations per function call. It is a major bottle neck since this routine is called many times. That said, I will research `deque` to see how it allocates upon insert, since I only need to it to be better than individual allocations (i.e. `vector<Node *>` with pointers into the heap)

Comment: @jeanluc: I'd give `std::deque` a try; it should avoid the pointer invalidation problem and keep down the number of allocations.

Answer (score 1):

A [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) does not move elements once added, so iterators and references are stable as long as you don't delete the referenced element.

Like `std::vector`, `std::deque` offers random access iterators. Random access into a deque is a little slower than `std::vector`, but still O(1). If you need stable references, the slight slow-down is probably acceptable.

Alternatively, instead of the pointer to the element, you could keep a reference to the vector and an index into the vector.